# Android retrieve data from SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-cursor

How do I retrieve data from `SQLite` database and display the information in `TextView` in other `Fragment` class using `ListView` `onItemClick`

I have a `ListView` containing the registered names only from database and after clicking `onItemClick` they will be directed to my `Fragment` class where I want to display the whole information using `TextView`

Here is my `Cursor` from my adapter class

```
public Cursor readData() {
    String[] allColumns = new String[] { SqlDbHelper._id, SqlDbHelper.COL_REG_ID, SqlDbHelper.COL_DOC_CODE,
            SqlDbHelper.COL_FNAME, SqlDbHelper.COL_LNAME, SqlDbHelper.COL_SPEC, SqlDbHelper.COL_CARD_ID,
            SqlDbHelper.COL_REGION, SqlDbHelper.COL_LOCATION, SqlDbHelper.COL_CONTACT };
    Cursor c = database.query(SqlDbHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use your MainActivity containing the two Fragments as a bridge and the Fragment with the Master-ListView has to implement onAttach() to store the MainActivity like shown in [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) example.
Every time the selected item changes the interface method of the MainActivity could be called and the MainActivity will pass the information of the selected item to the Details-Fragment, that queries for the selected item and updates the TextView. The user could change the text in the TextView and after pressing a save button an update query can be executed.